# Stylesheet reference with or without `.min`

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap, view

When redirecting to the stylesheets, using `.min` changed the layout.

I changed the code from from:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag("bootstrap-responsive.min", "bootstrap.min", "main", "normalize", :media => "screen")  %>
```

to:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag("bootstrap-responsive", "bootstrap", "main", "normalize", :media => "screen")  %>
```

And the page layout changed. Why is that? It links to the same file, why should there be any difference?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the order of your stylesheets has problem.

"bootstrap-responsive" should always be included after "bootstrap". So your original code already has problem.

I suggest you to change the order, clear browser cache, and try again.

Further more, it would be much better to utilize Assets Pipeline instead of including stylesheets manually in layout, no matter minified or not.

Comment: Even though this layout is different than the layout of the rest of the application?

Comment: @LucyWeatherford, I don't know what part changed, but it should be easy to check using browser debug tool. If your first result is not correct, you can't expect the remaining to be correct. Thus I suggest you to change the order at first to see correct effect.

Comment: I already changed the order, it helped, thanks; but it is still incorrect.. but closer

Comment: That's nice. Also it's better put your own JS code(if that is "main"?) always at the last.